# No suitable driver for postgres, even though Class.forName works?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm attempting to use the following Driver to connect to my postgresql database:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>9.4-1204-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm using the following code:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
System.out.println("Driver version: " + org.postgresql.Driver.getVersion());

String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432";
String user = "postgres";
String pass = "password"; // super secure

Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, user, pass);
```

And I get the following output

> Driver version: PostgreSQL 9.4 JDBC4.1 (build 1204)
>   
> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432
>   
>         at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
>   
>         at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
>   
>         at [ the line Connection c = DriverManager... ]

So how is it that this 9.4 driver is not suitable? I know I can log in via my psql command line, but I can't seem to get it to work through Java.

I've done apps like this many times, but can't seem to see what I'm missing here...

Comment: Try appending a databasename to the url: `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname`. Do you have other JDBC drivers on the classpath? Some actually intercept the way the DriverManager searches for the correct driver.

Comment: wow... I would have expected it to simply use the default database... Apparently I must be explicit... If you would like to create an answer, I'll be happy to give you credit for that.

Comment: Well, according to the manual, the database name is optional: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/connect.html

Comment: Any chance you are trying running  your app with Java 1.6?

Comment: Nope, the whole thing was fixed by adding a database name. It's just frustrating since that means I'll have to be on the database before I start the app, and I would rather it be entirely self-contained in the app. =( But horse's comment fixed my problem - just need him to make an answer so it's easy to find for future visitors with this problem. =)

Comment: Could you try `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/` (note the trailing `/`), instead of  `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All credit to a_horse_with_no_name's comment, but this question needs an answer.

Either specify a database in the connection string or add a trailing slash.

Bad url:

`jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432`

Good:

`jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/`

or

`jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/thebestdatabase`